# WordPress fails to load on a reverse proxy against a non-standard port

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I set up a nginx 1.21 reverse proxy on server wp.t.airbook.net.cn using the following loaction config:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
    proxy_send_timeout 1800s;
    proxy_pass https://wp.webtest.contentdeliver.net:14463;
}
```

Expected effect is that all traffic via https://wp.t.airbook.net.cn will get redirected to https://wp.webtest.contentdeliver.net:14463 and all the SSL things are taken care properly.

And then I set up a WordPress on https://wp.webtest.contentdeliver.net:14463 without a problem.

And in General Settings in WordPress Admin Panel I changed both the Home URL and Site URL to https://wp.t.airbook.net.cn and asked to log in again, also without a problem.

And, well, the weird thing happens:

1. I can use the WordPress Admin Panel via https://wp.t.airbook.net.cn so it indicates that the reverse proxy works;
2. However I cannot visit the WordPress site via https://wp.t.airbook.net.cn OR EVEN https://wp.webtest.contentdeliver.net:14463 ! It persists taking me to https://wp.webtest.contentdeliver.net on port 443!

Please help on where did I make mistake and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share the rest of your nginx config? There could be something wrong outside of the location block.

Comment: Only this location part matters. Other parts are only about ssl settings and log files etc. Also you may try https://wp.t.airbook.net.cn/wp-admin and you will see the reverse proxy works.